# store arrays in variables inside foreach

Tags: php, html

sorry if the title is not clear but what I need is something like this:

I have a foreach printing data from a db and I have multiple variables that should store the arrays and then print the main variable with all others variables.

```
foreach ($aItems as $i => $aItemInfo) {

    $var1 = '';
    $var2 = '';
    $var3 = '';
    $var1 .= $aItemInfo['val1'];
    $var2 .= $aItemInfo['val2'];
    $var3 .= $aItemInfo['val3'];

    // some operations with the db data
    if ($var1 > 0) {

        if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 0) {
            $a = 'Some text.';
        }
        else if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 1) {
            $a = 'Some other text.';
        }
        else if ($var1 > 1 && $var2 == 0) {
            $a = 'Some new text.';
        }
        else if ($var1 > 1 && $var2 == 1) {
            $a = 'Some other new text.';
        }

        $new_var = '';
        // html code
        $new_var .= '<div id="">
                        <a id="">' . $othervar . '</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="">
                        <span id="">' . $a . '</span>
                    </div>';
    }

    if ($var > 0) {
        // html code
        $other_var .= ' . $vars . ';
    }

    // html structure
    $main_var .= '';
}
```

And print the main variable:

```
<div class="">
    <?php echo $main_var; ?>
</div>
```

Actually some variables are the same than the previous. I tried placing a dot before "=" but I really have no idea how this works or what is for...

What I'm doing wrong? What is the correct way of make each variable so they can store each value of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `.=` concatenation properly in this case, that will just mess just those if conditions what you made.

Initial:

```
$var1 = '1';
if($var == 1) { // okay condition

}
```

Second iteration, another declaration again inside the loop. It will not do what you indend to do:

Just create something like this:

```
$main_var = $new_var = ''; // initialize output outtop
foreach ($aItems as $i => $aItemInfo) {

    if ($aItemInfo['val1'] == 1 && $aItemInfo['val2'] == 0) {
        $a = 'Some text.';
    }
    else if ($aItemInfo['val1'] == 1 && $aItemInfo['val2'] == 1) {
        $a = 'Some other text.';
    }

    // html code
    $new_var .= '
        <div id="">
            <a id="">' . $othervar . '</a>
        </div>
        <div id="">
            <span id="">' . $a . '</span>
        </div>
    ';


    if ($aItemInfo['val1'] > 0) {
        // html code
        // another process here whatever it is
    }

    // html structure
    $main_var .= $new_var;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I see my error. Please upvote me so I don't have -1 :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$var1 = $aItemInfo['val1'];
$var2 = $aItemInfo['val2'];
$var3 = $aItemInfo['val3'];

if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 0) {
    $a = 'Some text.';
}
else if ($var1 == 1 && $var2 == 1) {
    $a = 'Some other text.';
}
else if ($var1 > 1 && $var2 == 0) {
    $a = 'Some new text.';
}
else if ($var1 > 1 && $var2 == 1) {
    $a = 'Some other new text.';
}

if ($var > 0) {
    $new_var = '';
    // html code
    $new_var .= '<div id="">
                    <a id="">' . $othervar . '</a>
                </div>
                <div id="">
                    <span id="">' . $a . '</span>
                </div>';
}
```